# Parsing XML from Curl output

Tags: python, xml, bash, xml-parsing

When querying my internal API I get a bunch of responses. Those responses will tell me if a specific service is up/down.

Curl command:

```
curl https://myinternalapi.example.com/Ping/1.1
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><ping><service name="FBcheckOnline" status="down"/><service name="APICheckOn" status="up"/></ping>
```

I would like to parse the output data using Python/Bash. With the data parsed, I can then create `if` statements to check if a specific service is up or down.

The desired output would be something like:

```
FBcheckOnline down
APICheckOn up
```

How can I do that using Python (2.7) or Bash?

**EDIT 1**: I managed to get it working with Python 2.7

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('test.xml')
items = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('service')

for item in items:
    print item.attributes['name'].value, 
    print item.attributes['status'].value
```

However, I am trying to make it parse the data from a `curl` command instead of a file... or make the curl command to send the output to a file and then read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get what I needed with the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
#

from xml.dom import minidom
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("curl -s https://api.example.com/Ping/1.1 > curl_api_output_3.xml", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(output, err) = p.communicate()

xmldoc = minidom.parse('curl_api_output_3.xml')
items = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('service')

for item in items:
    print item.attributes['name'].value,
    print item.attributes['status'].value
```

Feel free to comment any tips you may have, as I am new in Python.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly parsing XML, but if output has consistent format, you can try something like,

```
curl -Ssk https://myinternalapi.example.com/Ping/1.1 | tr '<|/' '\n' | grep ^service | tr '+|=|"' ' ' | awk '{print $3, $NF}'
```